# Boost Spirit accept rule dynamically when a keyword is used

Tags: boost

I need some hint for the following problem.

```
Rule =   something >> ( EntryIsInsideKeyWordList >> ... ) 
       | ...
OtherRule = more >> detectnewkeyword [ put item in keyword list ]
```

And the item “EntryIsInsideKeyWordList” is a dynamic list which is built while the parser is running.
Can somebody point me to the documentation or starting point for such code ? Important is the first rule, use the dynamic keyword list for accepting ..

Comment: I saw this sample but this is only the second rule of my case. So putting the Keyword into a list .. the first rule is to use this dictionary "EntryIsInsdeKeyWordList" on a rule .. so far i can´t see a solution for this ..

Comment: Mmm. Solution to what problem? Can you share a sample that demonstrates the behaviour and what behaviour you need instead? I can (and will) reopen and answer if I can see the problem.